# Marker events such as dbclick(double click) and mouseover are not working

Tags: reactjs, mapmyindia-api

I tried the marker in my react js application but the marker events such as `dbclick` and `mouseover` are not working. I suspect any event other than click is not working. what can I do if I need the `onMouseOver` event?

I tried `markerobject.addListener("dbclick",function(){ console.log("double clicked!!")})`
but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

you don't use normally event listeners in React, instead you use events by React, I made a sample for you for different events:

```
export default function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <button
            onMouseEnter={() => console.log("testEnter")}
            onMouseLeave={() => console.log("test leave")}
            onMouseOver={() => console.log("Mouse over")}
            onDoubleClick={() => console.log("Double click")}
          >
            mouse over
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

[React Mouse Events reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events)